# Issue with rest services

Tags: php, rest

I am facing one issue while i am calling rest service using file_get_contents
its working fine when response is success but its giving blank result in case of failure or error response. while when I am checking it using rest client its giving me correct response for both case whether its success or failure.

can anyone please help? below is the source code which i have written.

```
    <?php

$postdata = array(
    'email' => $email,
    'password' => $password
);

$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'header' => $headers = array(
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Content-Type: application/json'
        )
    //'content' => $postdata
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
//echo "<pre>"; print_r($context); exit;
$url = WS_URL . "issavvy-api/account/login?" . http_build_query($postdata);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
echo "<pre>";
print_r(json_decode($result));
exit;
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `'ignore_errors' => true` to the context options?

Comment: I've never seen `file_get_contents` get used with REST web services. And it shouldn't get used like that. REST relies on HTTP communication. That means that besides setting up a request, you must parse the response. `file_get_contents` does not allow that. CURL does.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9659079/file-get-contents-vs-curl-for-invoking-apis-with-php

Comment: @AlexanderMP "and it shouldn't get used like that" sounds a lot like an opinion; php streams work fine for REST service consumption; not sure what you meant by "cURL allows for response parsing" either.

Comment: @Jack, response code, response headers. I couldn't imagine writing the wrappers that I've written, with a superficial functionality that is offered by file_get_contents.
And yeah, it's an opinion, that's why it's a comment and not an answer. In some cases it might be best to use file_get_contents, but it's hard to imagine such a case.

Comment: Yeah, you're forced to use `$http_response_header` if you use `file_get_contents()`; using `fopen()` allows for a cleaner approach, though cURL is of course superior in that respect.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna stick with file_get_contents use $http_response_header and parse it

You can use this

```
function httpStatusCode($headers){
    $match = null;
    $pattern = "!(?P<version>HTTP/\d+\.\d+) (?P<code>\d+) (?P<status>.*)!";
    foreach($headers as $header){
        if(preg_match($pattern, $header, $match)){
            return $match['code'];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

To check if request was successful run

```
$success = (200 == httpStatusCode($http_response_header));
```

https://eval.in/145906